# Matplotlib marker annotation fontsize not shrinking below 1pt in PDF

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, size, marker

I have two ax.annotate statements in my code. First line text I want to be big. Second line text should scale down.

```
for i,j,k in zip(x_power,y_power,net_name_power):
    ax.annotate(str(k),  xy=(i, j), color='white', fontsize=1, weight='light', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='bottom')
    ax.annotate('{} , {}'.format(str(round(i,3)),str(round(j,3))),  xy=(i, j), color='blue', fontsize=0.1, weight='light', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='top')
```

ax.annotate's fontsize doesn't scale below fontsize=1.

[Illustration of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Au1.png)

In the image, the white text is fontsize=1, whereas the blue text is fontsize=0.1. But as one can see, both texts are of the same size.
I am dumping the plot in PDF format, using *plt.savefig('output.pdf')*
.

I want the blue text to scale down so as to fit neatly in the red circular marker. Can somebody suggest a solution?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the minimum font point size is 1 -- see the source code here:

```
if size < 1.0:
    _log.info('Fontsize %1.2f < 1.0 pt not allowed by FreeType. '
              'Setting fontsize = 1 pt', size)
    size = 1.0
```

You could try using the string descriptors instead:

For example: `fontsize='xx-small'`

```
font_scalings = {
    'xx-small': 0.579,
    'x-small':  0.694,
    'small':    0.833,
    'medium':   1.0,
    'large':    1.200,
    'x-large':  1.440,
    'xx-large': 1.728,
    'larger':   1.2,
    'smaller':  0.833,
    None:       1.0,
```

Comment: Thanks @mullinscr . I tried using fontsize='xx-small' ,  but unfortunately, the blue text got even bigger than the minimum size (fontsize=1).

Like this :
https://i.imgur.com/hZiYou0.png

Comment: In which case your best bet may be to scale everything else up to fit the text in.

Comment: I tried scaling everything in my plot. I am plotting scatter plot xy with two variables **x_coords** and **y_coords**.
`x_coords = [i*5 for i in x_coords ]` and 
`y_coords = [i*5 for i in y_coords ]`
And then, 
`plt.axis([0, max(x_coords), 0, max(y_coords )])`.
Only the tick values scale, but everything in the plot remains same.
Is this the right way of doing it?